# Connecting to Bluetooth devices from Python for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth

I've spent a good time searching, but cannot find a solution that does not require installing C++ compilers.  Surely in 2023 there is a way to use Bluetooth from Python with pure Python or at least a pre-built module?

Comment: No C++: https://github.com/btframework/WCL-Python-Demos/tree/main/Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

Although Bleak requires a C++ backend, it is precompiled for many versions.  Installing Bleak on Windows 11 and Python 3.11 does not require installed C++ compilers; pip will download a pre-built binary.